# Send expanded R code snippet to the VSCode terminal running R

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I use VSCode (with the VIM extension enabled) to edit R code. I would like to define snippets that will be expanded with selected code or the word under the cursor and then be evaluated in the terminal.

Example:

```
foo <- 1
^
cursor position
```

I would like to define a snippet, e.g. `str(%w)`, where `%w` will be replaced with the word under the cursor so that the code becomes `str(foo)`, which will then be evaluated in the terminal, where an R session is running.

What would be the best solution to achieve this in VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc's of the vscode-r extension give some hints at https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/Keyboard-shortcuts. This is not as versatile as I would like it to be but good enough for now.

This is the entry I added to keybindings.json:

```
{
    "description": "r::str()",
    "key": "ctrl+f2",
    "command": "r.runCommandWithSelectionOrWord",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r",
    "args": "str($$)"
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to actually provide a solution here instead of just vaguely linking to an external website.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send `str(<your text here>)` to the terminal you can do that with a keybinding (in `keybindings.json`) like this:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+down",                        // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {

    // "text": "str(${selectedText}\u000D"   // execute immediately

    "text": "str(${selectedText}"            // press return to execute
  },

  // "when": "editorHasSelection && editorLangId == r"
  // if 'r' is the correct language identifier
}
```

There is no variable like `${currentWord}` unfortunately so you will have to select the text first.  Available [variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference).

`\u000d` is a unicode <kbd>Return</kbd> so that version executes immediately.